# Does this compound interest problem coincide to the value of e by coincidence?

Tags: calculus, number-theory

An account starts with €$1.00$ and pays $100\%$ interest per year. If the interest is credited once, at the end of the year, the value of the account at year-end will be €$2.00$ . What happens if the interest is computed and credited more frequently during the year?

I found, from Wiki, that if there are n compounding intervals, the interest for each interval will be $\dfrac{100\%}{n}$ and the value at the end of the year will be $1.00\times\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$. But, I was wondering how this compound interests problem relates directly, or indirectly, to the value of $e$ ?

Comment: When there's an irrational number involved, there is no such thing as coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$e=\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac 1n)^n$$

Comment: Yes, but does this have any graphical representation between the compound interest and e?

Comment: If you compound annualy, then monthly, then daily, then secondly, then milli-secondly, then every single instant in time, then you will approach $e$. Also, if you look at the graph of (1+1/n)^n, you see how as it is compounded more and more often, it approaches e.

Comment: $(1 + 1/n)^n$ is what you end up with if you start with $1$, and you're credited interest equal to one $n$th of your current balance, $n$ times.